# Spring Cloud Stream vs Google Native Library

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, publish-subscribe, spring-cloud-stream, google-cloud-pubsub

Google provides its own library to access pub/sub service. On the other hand Spring Cloud Stream also provides the same. Is there any advantage of one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pub/Sub is a Google Cloud Platform Product. It is developed, produced and mantianed by Google.

GCP offers you several ways of interacting with Pub/Sub, like using its web UI, using the command line or using its different client-libraries (which are supported in python, java, go, php, ruby...).

Spring Cloud Stream has partnered with Google in order to allow you to interact with Pub/Sub from its side.

Of course, if you are interested in using some other Spring Cloud Stream together with Pub/Sub probably that is a considerable option.

Otherwise, if you are interested in using only Pub/Sub or using it with some other product that is not related to SCS, the best option is to use any of the direct methods that Google Cloud Platform offers.